# Deriving column from values of previous two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame and want to create a new column based on the following logic

- Given a user_id
- Check if the event field in the previous row and the current row contains the same value
- Check that the time difference between the two events is less than a threshold

I have the following code for that

```
def calc_prev(row):    
    row_minus_1 = row.shift(1)
    row_minus_2 = row.shift(2)
    return ((row.event_type == 'roll') and 
            (row.event_type == row_minus_1.event_type == row_minus_2.event_type) and
            (row.ts - row_minus_1.ts < 500) and (row_minus_1.ts - row_minus_2.ts < 500))



df['new_metrics'] = df.groupby(['user_id']).apply(calc_prev)
```

For each row where the condition is true, I want the 'new_metrics' columns to contain 1. The code above gives me this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
    user_id event   ts  new_metrics
0   1   "start" 1531827851982   0
1   2   "end"   1531827852082   0
2   3   "start" 1531827852182   0
3   3   "start" 1531827852282   0
4   3   "start" 1531827852382   1
```

Comment: Can you provide some input data so we can verify your problem and test solutions?

Comment: The error happens when you use the boolean operators `and, or, not` on numpy arrays or pandas series, rather than the equivalent bitwise operators `&, |, ~`. If you replace the `and` with `&` in the return statement, the error will go away, but its difficult to say if that solves your problems without seeing any sample data or expected output

Comment: Thanks not. Added some sample data. The new_metrics column is the derived output. So, it should be 1 in row 4 as the previous 2 events for the same user_id matches and the difference between each ts is less than 500